Small, distance 2 quantum codes with transversal Clifford group
Are there any small, distance 2 quantum codes with a transversal Clifford group? For example, the 7-qubit Steane code is distance 3 but has the full single-qubit Clifford group. Are there smaller distance 2 codes that have the same property?
Ideally, the gate implementation is as simple as possible. For example, the [[4,2,2]] code has a transversal S, but it requires a physical CZ to implement.

On the $[4,1,2]$ code given by (the redundant) stabilizer group generators
$$\langle XYZI, IXYZ, ZIXY, YZIX \rangle$$
the Clifford group can be implemented by permutations followed by local Clifford gates as described in section 5.1 of Genons, Double Covers and Fault-tolerant Clifford Gates
